# SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544721] Unable to complete network request to host - laravel y firebird

Tags: laravel, firebird, packages, host, connection

Buen día,

Me encuentro realizando una consulta hacia una base de datos firebird remota desde Laravel, mas específicamente, utilizando el paquete "harrygulliford/laravel-firebird". Al realizar la petición desde mi servidor local, todo funciona correctamente, pero al montar la estructura a un servicio de host (GoDaddy), se produce el error SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544721] Unable to complete network request to host xxx.xx.xxxx

He revisado las configuraciones de firebird, asi como las de php, pero no logro dar con el problema.

Gracias de antemano por su colaboración

Dejo la configuración como la manejo desde el .env de Laravel

```
DB_CONNECTION=firebird
DB_HOSTFB=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DB_PORTFB=3050
DB_DATABASEFB='D:\TESTDATABASE\2021.GDB'
DB_USERNAMEFB=SYSDBA
DB_PASSWORDFB=masterkey
DB_CHARSETFB=UTF8
DB_VERSIONFB=2.5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338165/firebird-unable-to-complete-network-request-to-host